# How do I get the handle to a brush, Win32 C++

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, brush

I'm creating a Dialog window with some button controls. I want the buttons to be coloured individually. I've searched and found something that I think I should use, the [WM_CTLCOLORBTN Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761849%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

As stated the return value should be a "handle to a brush".

I can create a brush, for example like this:

```
HBRUSH blueBrush=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,255,0));
```

but how do I return the handle to this brush?

EDIT: My message handling function is defined as

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ClientDlgProc(...)
```

and if I try to return blueBrush I get this error:

error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'HBRUSH' to 'LRESULT'

Comment: If someone knows a better way of colouring my buttons, please let me know.

Comment: The answers below are correct, but note that you have a leak here. You need to store the HBRUSH somewhere for the lifetime of the dialog and DestroyObject() it afterwards. Normally it is created in WM_INITDIALOG and destroyed in WM_DESTROY.

Comment: I just haven't gotten that far yet ^^'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the value returned by CreateSolidBrush is the handle (the H in HBRUSH stands for 'handle').

Comment: Oh ok. I guess my real question is how to return this as an LRESULT, see edit in original question.

Comment: In that case, a simple cast should do the trick: return (LRESULT)blueBrush ;

Comment: Thanks, it works, the button turns green.. But it's flat, without a border and I can't see the text. Doh :(

Answer (score 0):

An `HBRUSH` is the handle to the brush. Return `blueBrush`.